# add_rewrite_rule() to route to file other than index.php

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^invite/([^/]+)',
    'index.php?pagename=invite&iid=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

The "internal" rewrite rule above will route traffic through `index.php` using the `pagename` argument (which necessitates having a page with slug `invite`).

I want to direct routing to `invite.php` (which will render an ICS calendar file and force download).

I looked into the below implementation, however, this appears to directly modify `.htaccess` file. My site is using nginx so this won't work.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^invite/([^/]+)',
    'invite.php?iid=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

Comment: [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82528/4771) might help you.

Comment: Thanks. That answer run a new `WP_Query` under their specific conditions. In my case, I am diverting to a file that has non-WP logic, not tied to any post type etc. My `invite.php` sets a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=invite.ics` header to force a download and echo's a var (which becomes the downloaded files content)

Comment: The contents of that `if` condition are irrelevant to the answer, just remove that code and put your own logic inside.

Comment: Right. The logic I need within `parse_query` to use `invite.php` isn't clear to me. Thanks for the answer but it doesn't really solve the issue

Comment: [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/220616/126589) answer helps. I need to `include` invite.php and then `exit()`

Comment: or just remove `invite.php` entirely and put whatever code is in that file within the function instead.

Answer (score -2):

```
add_action('parse_query', function(&$wp_query) {

    if (array_key_exists('iid', $wp_query->query_vars) && $wp_query->query['pagename'] === 'invite') {

        $iid = get_query_var('iid');

        // Do some stuff

        exit();

    }

    return;

});
```

Comment: what is that? a blob of code by itself is not an answer